# Get authentication username from shinyapp.io

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to track users for my shiny app. I simply just want their authentication username when login.

I tried to get the username by `name <- session$user`, and append this new line into the pre-exists table through `write.table(name, file = ".../.../data.csv", append = T, row.names = F, col.names = F)`

A simplified version of my app looks like:

```
mig_data <- read.csv('db/data.csv')
mb <- unique(mig_data$basket_name)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("My shiny Sample"),
    br(),
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel('zm', highchartOutput('zmdata')))
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$zmdata <- renderHighchart({
      hc <- highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "Web", data = mig_data[(mig_data$store_name== 'aloha' & mig_data$status == 'Web'),]$price) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = mb)
    })

     session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      whom <- session$user
      isolate(write.table(whom, file = "db/userlog.csv", append = T, row.names = F, col.names = F))
})

app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I open the deployed shiny app on shiny.io, there's nothing wrote into the `userlog.csv` table. (Which I do expect my email address appears.)

Just wondering if anyone has any idea on this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to make your app private and then if you login you should see your email.

Comment: @SNT ah yes, I should've noticed it! Thanks!